# Combine the second element of Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq

I have an array of objects called orders for holding the list of item GUIDs and their quantity.

```
Dim orders As Object(,) = {{"ItemA", 11}, {"ItemB", 10}, {"ItemA", 2}, {"ItemB", 1}}
```

I want to convert that to following:

```
Dim orders As Object(,) = {{"ItemA", 13}, {"ItemB", 11}}
```

in other words, I want to have a distinct select of the items with the combined quantity of records for that item. 
can I do this with LINQ or should I just use the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` to group by GUID

```
Dim orders As Object(,) = {{"ItemA", 11}, {"ItemB", 10}, {"ItemA", 2}, {"ItemB", 1}}

Dim ordersSum As New Dictionary(Of String, Int32)()
For orderIndex As Int32 = 0 To orders.GetUpperBound(0)
    If ordersSum.ContainsKey(orders(orderIndex, 0)) = True Then
        ordersSum(orders(orderIndex, 0)) += orders(orderIndex, 1)
    Else
        ordersSum.Add(orders(orderIndex, 0), orders(orderIndex, 1))
    End If
Next
```

Then if `Dictionary` type not allowed and you really need a multidimensional array as return type

```
Dim result As Object(,) = New Object(ordersSum.Count - 1, 1) {}
Dim index As Int32 = 0
For Each key As String In ordersSum.Keys
    result(index, 0) = key
    result(index, 1) = ordersSum(key)
    index += 1
Next
```